# Panel Data Estimation-Fixed vs First Difference Estimation

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, pooling

I am running a panel data regression on a set of 50 countries for a period of 25 years.

I find some of my X (Independent) variable are stationary at first difference while one of the independent variable is stationary at levels.

My question being: To get efficient estimate do I need to run a Fixed Effects model since one of the variable is stationary at levels.

Any help regarding this would be of great use to me.
Thanks in advance.

Sagnik

Comment: Welcome to CV. The canonical source for questions of this type is Wooldridge's *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*, particularly chapter 10. That said, stationarity is typically not a concern with the independent variables as the focus is on the behavior of the dependent variable. You would need to explain more about your data to be able to address issues of fixed vs random effects.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I have been following the Wooldrige's (2002) book. I would again go back deeper into it.